# How to solve matrix valued ODE in Python?

Tags: python, differential-equations

I need to solve the following kind of equation :

d/dt J[t] = H[t].J[t]

Here, both H[t] and J[t] are NxN square matrices, and the initial condition being J[0]= Identity matrix of NxN dimensions. In my problem, N will be 20 or 30.

Basically, I want to flow J[t] till some time T and find the determinant of J[T] given I know what J[0] is.

How can this be done in Python ( or Mathematica)?

Comment: `math` module can do all math related processing in Python. Very useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Comment: You need to either wrap the ODE function in reshape/flatten yourself, or use the odeintw wrapper that does essentially the same.